# CSS CheckBox Hack for Click Event not Works when nested in a DIV

Tags: css, checkbox

How i can add the checkbox and label css click event inside a DIV?
the below codes not works for me, if i remove "" its working perfect.
Why is happening?

---

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
       <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="hub" class="hub"  style="display:none;"/>
       <label for="hub"  class="hub2"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="slide"> 
       the contents
    </div>
```

---

### CSS

```
.slide{
    background:red; 
}


input[type=checkbox].hub:checked ~ .slide {
    background:green !important;    
}
```

Comment: .hub and .slide are not in the same node, ~ is for siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put your `.slide` element along with the `label` and the `input[type=checkbox]`, like following

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="hub" class="hub"  style="display:none;"/>
   <label for="hub"  class="hub2">open</label>
   <div class="slide"> 
      the contents
   </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/TBjtD/)</kbd>

<kbd>[More on sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector)</kbd>

Comment: without js no, you cannot, the css selector only allow children or descendent siblings